# How do I build Qt 3.X.X on Windows?

Tags: c++, qt

I downloaded a project that depends on Qt 3.X.X (legacy version). I downloaded this version from the Qt downloads archive and set the environment variables according to what the documentation tells me. I can't build the program though. The errors I get are all along the lines of

```
Moc'ing SomeFile.h ...
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Looking into the Qt /lib folder, there's just one README file that says

> If this directory is empty, you forgot to build the Qt library

I'm assuming this is the reason I can't build my project, so I would like to know how to build this Qt version. The documentation is extremely limited since it's an old version, so I can't get it to work based on that.

Some system info:

- Windows 10
- x64
- Visual Studio 2015 installed

If you need more info, please let me know!

Comment: Qt 3.x would require several changes to get it to compile on modern compilers. Instead, use Qt 4.x and enable Qt 3 compatibility APIs. Feel free to mention what project is that, perhaps it can be easily ported to Qt 4.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks! I'll try Qt4. The project is https://github.com/arnaudgelas/mesh